# Is there a way to access Bluetooth 4.0 Low Energy devices in iOS?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

The new iPhone 4S has support for Bluetooth 4.0 Low Energy devices.  Is there an API for communicating with these devices in iOS?

Answer (score 20):

It is [part of the iOS 5.0 SDK](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CoreBluetooth_Framework/_index.html). You can download the SDK and check it out.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CoreBluetooth_Framework/_index.html

Comment: Michael, you should accept the answer to follow up on the communities guide lines.

Answer (score 5):

As someone has mentioned, the APIs are available in the iOS 5.0 SDK. However, bear in mind that those APIs only provide support for ATT client, if you want to add services and act as a server you're out of luck for now. I truly hope Apple will add server support at some point, since some profiles (Alert Notification or Proximity) would benefit enormously: being able to be notified when you receive a new SMS/email or being able to "ping" your phone to find it would be great.

Comment: When you refer to client ATT support, you mean access to server capabilities?For instance, API that can only be used to access data coming from a heart rate low power 4.0 device? because if its like this,i havent found on this API information about how to connect to a server profile like the ones used for sensors (heart rate profile,tempeture sensor profile,etc).thank you very much in advance

Comment: here i got an official statement: http://9to5mac.com/2011/10/24/iphone-4s-a-bluetooth-smart-ready-device-as-bluetooth-4-0-gets-rebranded/#more-102322.

Comment: I mean that you can use the API to access the database of a remote device acting as an ATT server. iOS 5 is the ATT client and you can read/write characteristics from/to a remote device's database. To know which characteristics correspond to what data (heart rate, temp, etc) you need to use the UUIDs in bluetooth.org and match them with the iOS APIs. If you read the profile specifications along with the API this should all become clear.

Comment: ,now i think i got it.What you mean is that IOS5 only supports ATT layer (Attribute Protocol) for raw transactions,but not GAP and GATT frameworks for ATT.I was confused,because on the official spec of HRP profile v10,it demands,as mandatory,GATT profile for this service (HRP in our case)on the sensor device,and at the collector device (phone as central role).But GATT is just a framework that works on ATT,so as you said,the HRP service can be accessed from iphone by ATT transactions.Would be awesome if there was example code for ATT like ChatApp on Android RFCOMM :-).thanks so much.

Comment: iOS 6 has server capabilities

Answer (score 4):

TI has a nice development package that includes a BLE peripheral, programmer, sample code, and sample iOS App. This is a great place to start and shows off most aspects of the Core Bluetooth API in iOS

http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Category:BluetoothLE